# prevent returning pem files from nodejs express

Tags: node.js, security, express, pem

I want to prevent nodejs from returning my secret pem files to the world. Using express, I have

```
app.use(express.static('html'), function (req, res, next)
{
  var pathname = parseurl(req).pathname
  if (pathname.indexOf('.pem') >= 0)
    res.status(403).send('<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>')
  else
    next()
});
```

but i am still able to download the .pem file from my website (which is a security concern for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you move your .pem (and any other sensitive files) completely out of any path that node/express thinks is serve-able content.

I would worry that even if you get your sample code to work, your pem is vulnerable to a current or future node/express exploit.

You don't want the equivalent of locks-on-car-doors protecting your secrets ;-)

Comment: that makes sense. so if i move the .pem file up one directory (outside of the html directory), i should still be able to access it in my javascript by saying var path_to_pem='../mypem.pem';

Comment: When you say in your javascript, do you mean server side in node, or client side? I don't think you want anything client side able to access sensitive files. But server side, yeah you could put it in any directory you have RW access to.

Comment: yeah so i'd create an end-point for /api/push (which is public... im still thinking on how to deal with that), but the .pem is not in the html served content